# How do you add a custom shallow route when nested under another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to add a custom action on a controller that is nested under another and struggling. Here are my current routes:

```
resources :employers do
   resources :import_files, shallow: true 
end
```

I want to add the route: **"import_files#download"** with the path like: **'import_files/:id(.:format)/download'**

This can't be as hard as I'm making it, thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config/routes.rb` file, put:

```
get 'import_files/:id(.:format)/download', to: 'import_files#download'
```

EDIT if you want a path helper then

```
get 'import_files/:id(.:format)/download', to: 'import_files#download', as: 'download'
```

Then you can use `download_path(id)` in your rails app.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to put it under a random path helper then. Do I need the as: after or something for the helper?